# pip installing from git vs cloning repo

Tags: python, git, pip, installation

**What I did**.
Following instructions, I installed the [torchdiffeq](https://github.com/rtqichen/torchdiffeq) package with

```
pip install git+https://github.com/rtqichen/torchdiffeq
```

**What I am missing**.
But that didn't clone the repository, in particular not `ode_demo.py` in the `examples` subdirectory.

**Probably not the right solution**.
If I clone the repo in order to get this `examples` subdirectory, then I will also have another copy of the `torchdiffeq` subdirectory, which I now already have installed (it is under `~/.pyenv/versions/torchdiffeq/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torchdiffeq`).

This just doesn't seem the right way to do things.

**The correct solution with "editable mode"?**
I read about [editable installs](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#editable-installs), but am not sure if that has anything to do with my issue (and what is an *"egg"*?).

**Understanding the install process**.
Is it simply looking at [`setup.py` file](https://github.com/rtqichen/torchdiffeq/blob/master/setup.py) and therefore only adding `torchdiffeq` and `torchdiffeq._impl` to the package list (here I am reaching the limits of my understanding of what `setuptools.setup()` does)?  In other words, is this telling me that it is ignoring the rest of the repo?

**Last remark**. 
The `git install` command says:

`Cloning https://github.com/rtqichen/torchdiffeq to /private/var/folders/sx/n_vsjpb907g774qmgxzmtv9r0000gn/T/pip-req-build-0uckfck8`

the latter being a *temporary* file, which seems to have been deleted once the install completed, so I am not able to see if the entire repo ever transited there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*pip* did clone the *git* repository as you say so yourself towards the end of your question. It was cloned in a temporary directory. *pip* then used this temporary to build and install the Python project into your current environment. Once this is done the temporary directory containing the cloned repository has been deleted.

The directories `torchdiffeq` and `torchdiffeq._impl` are declared as *packages* of this project (listed in the parameter to the `packages` argument of the `setuptools.setup()` function call in `setup.py`) and are meant to actually be installed. Other directories are not meant to be installed, so *pip* didn't install them.

If you want to use the examples, then you can keep your own clone of the *git* repository and use them against the installed version of the project. Unless you want to modify the code of the project itself there is not much point in using the *editable* mode.

Comment: In other words, the probably-not-the-right-solution seems the most viable?  In this particular instance, it was easy enough to copy-paste just the one file `ode_demo.py`, but in general I would simply ignore the copy of the project contained in the repo.

Comment: Yes, seems viable. There is just one subtlety: if I am not mistaken the current directory is by default in Python's `sys.path`. So I believe that if you are at the root of the _git_ clone of the project, then the installed version might be masked by the project in your current directory. So if you do `python examples/ode_demo.py` then I am not sure which code is gonna be imported (installed or current directory). This has no consequence as long as the installed version and the cloned version (current directory) are exactly the same.